# How to put SSIS parametre in Odata Connector

Tags: ssis, odata

i work on SSIS package with Odata connector when i use filtrer with value it's work fine but when i want to change the value and replace it by parametre to make it more dynamic i have error bad request

[when i put value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbhTw.png)

[when i put parametre SSIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSb6g.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzTsC.png)

[value of parametre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZORP.png)

I've tried several syntex but I don't see the possibility to put expressions SSIS in the Odata filter